# ¿Por qué al deserializar una lista de una clase que tengo, solo me devuelve un solo elemento? c# windows forms

Tags: c#, lista, archivo, clase, serialización

```
public frmlista(string _nombrearchivo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        nombrearchivo = _nombrearchivo;

        Stream archivo = File.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.directorio + "\\" + nombrearchivo + ".cde", FileMode.Open);

        if (archivo.Length > 0)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formateador = new BinaryFormatter();

            List<Pregunta> preguntas = formateador.Deserialize(archivo) as List<Pregunta>;


            clistapreguntas.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var pregunta in preguntas)
            {
                string cuestion = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < pregunta.cuestion.Length; i++)
                {
                    cuestion += pregunta.cuestion[i];
                }

                clistapreguntas.Items.Add(cuestion);
            }

        }
        archivo.Close();
    }
```

Este es el código que tengo para deserializar, al momento de que se abre el archivo, lógicamente debe checar si ya tiene datos guardados ahi o no, por lo que ahi no hay problema.

Al colocar un punto de interrupción, y checar paso por paso los valores de mi lista preguntas, hay un problema, y es que el valor Count = 1 cuando debería ser 2 o más porque al momento de serializarlo, es con lo que se supone que se guarda al archivo.
***Quiero decir, que no carga todos los elementos de la lista, solo el primero.***

Acá esta el otro código dónde serializo.

```
private void cbotonañadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Pregunta> preguntas = null;
        frmmodificar Frmmodificar = new frmmodificar();

        BinaryFormatter formateador = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream archivo = File.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.directorio + "\\" + nombrearchivo + ".cde", FileMode.Open);

        if (archivo.Length > 0)
        {
            preguntas = formateador.Deserialize(archivo) as List<Pregunta>;
        }
        else
        {
            preguntas = new List<Pregunta>();
        }

        if (Frmmodificar.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            preguntas.Add(Frmmodificar.pregunta);
            formateador.Serialize(archivo, preguntas);

            string cuestion = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < Frmmodificar.pregunta.cuestion.Length; i++)
            {
                cuestion += Frmmodificar.pregunta.cuestion[i];
            }

            clistapreguntas.Items.Add(cuestion);
        }
        archivo.Close();
    }
```

Así que el problema final es, que no se si se serializo bien o no, porque checo el tamaño del archivo creado y manipulado y cada vez el tamaño aumenta.
El problema puede ser al deserializar?

1. Abrir archivo
2. Checar si dicho archivo ya tiene datos guardados
3. Deserializarlo y guardarlo a la lista preguntas
4. Modificar la lista, añadir, eliminar, etc. y volverlo a serializar al archivo

Pensé que quizas debería vaciar el archivo y serializarlo de nuevo... puede ser?

Comment: File open esta haciendo que el archivo se abra y grabe datos al final. Eso queres?

Comment: Pues el archivo para ese entonces ya esta creado. Supongo que debo usar FileMode.open.

Comment: Vos estas queriendo agregar todo el objeto de nuevo, y agregar cosas a un archivo ya creado??? o bajar todo de vuelta, de cero...???

Comment: Estos son los pasos.
Primero crear un archivo
Luego añadirle una pregunta a la lista
Serializar la lista al archivo

Y la siguiente vez que se vuelva a abrir el archivo,
Deserializar todas las preguntas
Mostrar todas las preguntas ya creadas
Agregar más preguntas al objeto
Serializar de nuevo.

Comment: esos cuales? podrias ser mas claro???

Comment: Modificare la publicacion, al final ves los pasos mejor definidos, en los comentarios no puedo jeje

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione yo solo, creí que me tomaría un tiempo pero parecio ser una tonteria...

```
private void cbotonañadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Pregunta> preguntas = null;
        frmmodificar Frmmodificar = new frmmodificar();

        BinaryFormatter formateador = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var archivo = File.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.directorio + "\\" + nombrearchivo + ".cde", FileMode.Open))
        {

            if (archivo.Length > 0)
            {
                preguntas = formateador.Deserialize(archivo) as List<Pregunta>;
            }
            else
            {
                preguntas = new List<Pregunta>();
            }

            if (Frmmodificar.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                preguntas.Add(Frmmodificar.pregunta);
                archivo.Close();

                using (Stream truncado = File.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.directorio + "\\" + nombrearchivo + ".cde", FileMode.Truncate))
                {
                    formateador.Serialize(truncado, preguntas);

                    string cuestion = null;

                    for (int i = 0; i < Frmmodificar.pregunta.cuestion.Length; i++)
                    {
                        cuestion += Frmmodificar.pregunta.cuestion[i];
                    }

                    clistapreguntas.Items.Add(cuestion);

                    truncado.Close();
                }
            }
            archivo.Close();
        }
    }
```

El problema fue que la serialización, al poner fileMode.open siempre, se escribia al final como me dijo en los comentarios, pero no sabía como abrir el archivo, deserializarlo, vaciarlo y serializarlo de nuevo.
Opte por esta solución pero si se les ocurre una mejor idea haganmela saber si pueden.